# How to avoid Bot repeating command in groups?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I created a new Telegram Bot which maintains a simple list. When I chat with the Bot directly (in PMs) the Bot works as intended.

[image: Working as intended]

I created this bot for a group of friends, so I added the bot to the group, and now, whenever I execute a command, the bot responds, but also repeats my command. Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

[image: Bot in Group]

I am using the python-telegram-bot API and sending messages using `update.message.reply_text('My message')`

Is this just intended behavior or is there any way to avoid the bot repeating the sent command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Telegram API understands this as quoting, and is enabled in groups by default, disabled in private chats.
It can be disabled by using:

```
update.message.reply_text("message", quote=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The bot only is replying message, not creating 2 messages.

You should use send_message.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. So in the API its called quoting, and can be disabled also with: 
update.message.reply_text(message, quote=False)

Comment: @Nieuwefn could you put this answer as correct? with green check